# Is there a typical way of releasing npm modules, like gitflow but for small modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, npm, git-flow

Gitflow is good for large applications with long release branches and many contributors.

On the other hand, NPM modules are tend to be small and focused, often having a single contributor only. Gitflow looks like an overhead or even a significant dragger when a module does a series of `-alpha` releases (see [Semver](http://semver.org/)).

What is the typical way to develop, maintain, and release NPM modules hosted in a git repo?

Comment: Questions asking for some third party resource are considered off-topic on Stack Overflow.  If you describe a specific problem you have, then you may be able to craft an on-topic question asking how to solve that problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 rephrased the question. Better now?

Comment: Improved.  But, it's still a pretty broad question with lots of potential answers which will mostly be someone's opinion (which is still a problem here).  There is no official "standard" for how to develop, maintain and release NPM modules.  There are lots of different ways to do so and which way is "best" will vary from one developer to another depending upon needs, preferences and opinions.'  I'm wondering if your question fits better in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00. I have just replaced the "standard" with "typical". In case this question gets closed I would go to programmers.se.com. Cheers!